# How can I automate radio buttons to click?

Tags: html, user-interface, select, radio-button

As I can do that when I click a radio button automatically select another?

example: http://www.eharmony.com/online/

I am a man and I'm looking female or woman seeking a man

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#myRadio').on('change', function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#myOtherRadio').prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
```